# chrome.tabs.create in incognito window opens a tab in normal window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

This bug has been reported here too(closed as obsolete):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72948

I want to create a new `tab` in current `incognito window` . The call to `chrome.tabs.create` will be made in background page. How can I achieve this? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Yes. I have checked Allow in Incognito. I can see my extension icon in incognito window too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well guys I made it work after adding permission `"incognito":"split"` in `manifest.json`

It is explained in the docs :

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the permission {"incognito":"split"} didn't solve my problem. The user must grant incognito right to the extension via extension manager details. Now it works: I get the window object from the callback when creating the incognito window.